# How to inherit Eq class in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I want to define new class PersonOP which inherit Eq class.
I mean I have a data type

```
data Person a = {name:a,age:Int}
```

i want to create a class like

```
   class (Eq a)=> PersonOp a where
```

and then make instance like this

```
   instance PersonOp (Person a) where

         (Person a)==(Person a) = equality (Person a) (Person a)
```

when i implement something like in class

```
     (==)::a->a->Bool 
     x==y = not (x/=y)
```

i got error how can i fix it?

Comment: why not simply `a == a` in your instance definition?

Comment: What do you want a class for? Are you just trying to compare `Person`s for equality? You don't need a class for that, just add `deriving (Eq)` to your `data` definition.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found answer

```
import Prelude hiding ((==))

data Person a = {name:a,age:Int}
class PersonOp a where
    (==)::a->a->Bool

instance PersonOp (Person a) where
    (Person a)==(Person a) = equality (Person a) (Person a)
```

Comment: there is nothing about "how to inherit Eq" in your answer.

Answer (score 13):

It would be simplest to derive equality for your person class:

```
data Person a = Person {name::a, age::Int}
   deriving Eq
```

so that you can do

```
*Main> Person "James" 53 == Person "Fred" 23
False
*Main> Person "James" 53 == Person "James" 53
True
```

This automatically creates an `==` function for `Person a` based on the `==` for `a`.

### Why

In haskell, `==` is a member of the `Eq` class. You can only define `==` by creating an instance of the `Eq` class, and if you try to define it otherwise, you will get an error.

Making it a part of a class makes it easy for you to define equality as appropriate for your data types.

### Defining an instance by hand

Instead of deriving `Eq`, you can define it yourself, so for example:

```
data Person a = Person {name::a, age::Int}

instance Eq a => Eq (Person a) where
   someone == another = name someone == name another
                      && age someone == age another
```

Comment: I think you meant to say "defining an __instance__ by hand"?

Comment: I found answer import Prelude hiding ((==))

Comment: @user2266517 But that stops you using `==` anywhere else in your program - you can't use `==` on integers or strings if you do this.